# Audio de fundo contínuo

Tags: html, html5-audio

Coloquei um audio de fundo no site com autoplay e loop, só que quando eu ia para outra página, o audio começava a tocar desde o início. Procurando pela net, achei um JavaScript que captura o tempo transcorrido do audio e, quando eu mudo de página, o audio continua de onde parou. O problema é, funciona no Firefox, mas no Chrome não.
Aqui o código que usei:

```
<audio preload="auto" src="../audio/The Clans Join.mp3" loop autobuffer> </audio>
<script>

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
      x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
      if (x==c_name)
        {
        return unescape(y);
        }
      }
}

var song = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
var played = false;
var tillPlayed = getCookie('timePlayed');
function update()
{
    if(!played){
        if(tillPlayed){
        song.currentTime = tillPlayed;
        song.play();
        played = true;
        }
        else {
                song.play();
                played = true;
        }
    }

    else {
    setCookie('timePlayed', song.currentTime);
    }
}
setInterval(update,1);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para resumir o *play* de um arquivo de áudio em determinada posição, o servidor precisa de estar configurado corretamente.

O navegador envia solicitações em [intervalos de *bytes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media#Handle_HTTP_1.1_byte_range_requests_correctly) <sup>(byte-range)</sup> para recolher e reproduzir determinadas regiões de um arquivo, pelo que, o servidor deve responder de forma adequada:

> A fim de suportar a localização e reprodução das regiões da mídia que ainda não foram descarregadas, Gecko faz uso de solicitações *byte-range* HTTP 1.1 para recolher a mídia a partir da posição alvo.
>
> Além disso, se não forem servidos os cabeçalhos *X-Content-Duration*, Gecko usa solicitações *byte-range* para procurar até ao fim da mídia (supondo que foi servido o cabeçalho *Content-Length*), a fim de determinar a duração da mídia.

Assim sendo, se o servidor responder a pedidos *byte-range* de forma correta, podes definir a posição inicial do audio com `currentTime`:

```
audio.currentTime = 30;
```

Ver: [Configuring servers for Ogg media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media) que se aplica também a outros formatos.

## Resposta

O teu problema está no servidor e na sua configuração em relação aos pedidos *byte-range*.

## Exemplo

Fica um exemplo para testes que está a funcionar corretamente no meu Google Chome, versão 41.0.2272.118 m a correr em Windows 8.1.

O audio é proveniente da WikiMedia e dado os servidores deles estarem configurados adequadamente para *byte-range*, ouço perfeitamente o trombone a partir do 10º segundo conforme exemplo que se segue.

```js
document.getElementById("all").addEventListener("click", function(event) {

  var song = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];

  song.currentTime = 0;
  song.play();

}, false);


document.getElementById("some").addEventListener("click", function(event) {

  var song = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];

  song.currentTime = 10;
  song.play();

}, false);
```

```html
<audio src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Tromboon-sample.ogg">
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
<button id="all">Ouvir do ínicio</button>
<button id="some">Ouvir a partir do 10º segundo</button>

<p>Reparar que o ínicio e o resumo aos 10 segundos produzem sons bem diferentes o que nos permite apurar que isto funciona, assumindo a configuração correta do servidor.</p>
```

---

Creditos da resposta para [este tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9563887/352449) no SOEN que agrega toda a informação sobre este assunto desde 2012.